# python curses: disable pasting (ctrl+v)

Tags: python, curses, python-curses

If you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> with some chars in buffer, [`window.getch()`](http://screen.getch()) will handle each char from buffer in course.
Is there any option either to:

- handle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> shortcut with curses
- ignore all terminal or OS shortcuts

Comment: That's unrelated to curses; your **terminal** might have some relevant feature.